# The default CSS of Django admin section is not loading

Tags: css, django, nginx

Folks, the default CSS of my Django admin section is not loading (setup uses nginx reverse proxy + gunicorn, OS is the Debian-based Ubuntu).

The following is part of `etc/nginx/sites-available/myproject`:

```
location /static/admin {

        alias /home/mhb11/.virtualenvs/myenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/;
    }
```

That, btw, points to the correct location of django admin's css files, and is written **below** `location /static/ {}` snippet (not shown here).

Note that I have tried the `root` directive instead of `alias` too, to no avail. Also note that this error pertains solely to django admin static files. The project related static files are **working perfectly**. Also note that my **settings.py** file includes `'django.contrib.staticfiles',` in INSTALLED_APPS and `STATIC_URL = '/static/'`.

What am I missing? *Please ask for more information in case it is needed.*

Comment: You should have defined a static_dir and run collectstatic.

Comment: Hey Daniel. I have `STATICFILES_DIRS = (
 os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)` in settings.py, if that's what you're implying. So you mean to say I should run `python manage.py collectstatic`?

Comment: Yes, that he meant, but for the command you have to specify the static_root (must be different unlike staticfiles_dirs, most common place is e.g. /var/www/your_domain/static/).

Comment: In settings.py I have `STATIC_ROOT = 'staticfiles'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may not be significant, but for consistency, your `location` path and `alias` path should both end with a `/` *or* neither end with a `/`.

With your current configuration, the server is constructing path names with an embedded `//`, like `/home/mhb11/.virtualenvs/myenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/static//somefile.css`.

Try:

```
location /static/admin/ {
    alias /home/mhb11/.virtualenvs/myenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Richard. Let me get back to you on whether this alleviated my problem.